# Disabling buttons before view rotates

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, rotation, uiimagepickercontroller

So been working on another app recently for iOS which incorporates a UIImagePickerViewController. App is ready to go and all works fine under normal circumstances, but if the user is being eratic and pushing buttons whilst rotating the iPad, then things go slightly awry and views load in the wrong place.

So basically, I want to disable all my buttons before the iPad is rotated and enable them again after the view is done rotating.

I thought this would be easy using the

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

and

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

methods.

But because the UIImagePickerController is being displayed, this for some reason stops these methods from being called. So I can't use these methods.

So basically, what I'm asking is if anybody can think of any other ways that I could achieve this??

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass UIImagePickerController and then implement those methods on your UIImagePickerController subclass.